# Can not match the last group of numbers using php preg_match()

Tags: php, regex

```
preg_match_all("/(\d{12})
(?:,|$)/","111762396541,561572500056,561729950637,561135281443",$matches);
```

var_dump($mathes):

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '561762396543,' (length=13)
      1 => string '561572500056,' (length=13)
      2 => string '561729950637,' (length=13)
      3 => string '561135281443' (length=12)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '561762396543' (length=12)
      1 => string '561572500056' (length=12)
      2 => string '561729950637' (length=12)
      3 => string '561135281443' (length=12)
```

But I want the $matches like this:

> ```
> array (size=4)
>   0 => string '561762396543,' (length=13)
>   1 => string '561572500056,' (length=13)
>   2 => string '561729950637,' (length=13)
>   3 => string '561135281443' (length=12)
> ```

I wanna match groups of numbers(each has 12 digits) and a suffix comma if there is one.The exeption is the last group of numbers,it doesnt have to match a comma,cause it reaches the end of the line.

Comment: use regex `\d{12}$`

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
preg_match_all("/(\d{12}(?:,|$))/","111762396541,561572500056,561729950637,561135281443",$matches);
```

When the $ is inside your character range brackets [ ] it is looking for the $ characters not the end-of-line.

EDIT: If you want to include the comma in your matches, then just use the above code sample and look at $matches[0].

<del>If you wanted an easier syntax that matches any sort of word boundary, the \b will match commas and end-of-line, too:
preg_match_all("/(\d{12}\b)/","111762396541,561572500056,561729950637,561135281443",$matches);</del>

Comment: thanks,I've re-edited my question,so you can get my intention precisely

Comment: So the initial code that I provided gives you what you want. The preg_match_all() will give you a $matches array where $matches[0] has the fully-matched string, while $matches[1] and on will match your captures. So based on your updates, you have what you need in $matches[0].Just var_dump($matches[0]) instead of var_dump($matches).

Comment: Great minds think alike, $matches[0] can do it.But I'm a perfectionist,I just wander which pattern can bring me  $matches[0] without  $matches[1].

Comment: Just remove the capture parentheses: /\d{12}(?:,|$)/ and you'll get $matches with just one child array ($matches[0]). However, preg_match_all() ALWAYS returns an array of arrays. It's not about perfectionism - that's just the normal way that function returns its matches.

Comment: Thanks for your great help,problem solved.I've learned a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Also, don't forget to accept the comment as the answer.